# Creating a script to print selection of pages (Automator?)

Tags: applescript, automator, printing

I would like to generate an Automator / Apple script that would:

1. Print even pages of a document
2. Wait for a button to be pressed
3. Print uneven pages of the same document.

Ideally accessible as a standard print option in the "PDF" submenu of the "Print" panel.

What strategy would you recommend?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You may find that functionality already exists within your printer driver. It would be wise to examine whether that's possible before attempting anything more complicated. Applescripts can only control the functionality of another program, and that program would have to support your requirement **and** expose the function to AppleScript. It might be possible by scripting some command line tools. What have you tried already?

Comment: Presumably, you want to print both sides of the paper on a printer without duplex? Many printers also have a "Manual duplex" option, which does this exactly.    Alternatively, you would just need to create a printer preset for printing Even pages, and another for printing Odd pages.

Comment: Yes indeed, as there is not such manual duplex option for my printer, I wanted to try automating the process